# Bitbucket Pipelines share SOME steps between branches

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Is it possible to share steps between branches and still run branch specific steps? For example, the develop and release branch has the same build process, but uploaded to separate S3 buckets.

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - cd source
          - npm install
          - npm build
  develop:
    - step:
        script:
          - s3cmd put --config s3cmd.cfg ./build s3://develop

  staging:
    - step:
        script:
          - s3cmd put --config s3cmd.cfg ./build s3://staging
```

I saw this post ([Bitbucket Pipelines - multiple branches with same steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304478/bitbucket-pipelines-multiple-branches-with-same-steps)) but it's for the same steps.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use YAML anchors:

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &Test-step
        name: Run tests
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run test
    - step: &Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to staging
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run build
          - fab deploy
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *Test-step
    - step: *Deploy-step
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *Test-step
      - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: production
        trigger: manual
```

Docs: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/yaml-anchors-960154027.html

Comment: It'd be nice to parameterize anchor calls, but it seams like it's not supported

Comment: There is a feature for that: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Is-it-possible-to-set-environment-variables-per-pipeline-step/qaq-p/941913

Answer (score 18):

<strike>Although it's not officially supported yet, you can pre-define steps now.</strike>
You can use [yaml anchors](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/).
I got this tip from bitbucket staff when I had [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/16136/start-pipeline-on-feature-branch) running the same steps across a subset of branches.

```
definitions:
  step: &Build
    name: Build
    script:
      - npm install
      - npm build

pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *Build
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *Build
      - step:
          name: deploy
          # do some deploy from master only
```

Comment: Two notes here:
1) definitions block must be before pipelines block (yamllint allows both but not bitbucket)
2) to share many steps, give a unique name to each: `step-build: &build` then `- step: &step-build`

Comment: It's been 4 years, is this official yet?

Comment: The right search terms yields an answer:  https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/

Answer (score 6):

I think Bitbucket can't do it. You can use one pipeline and check the branch name:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - cd source
          - npm install
          - npm build 
          - if [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH = develop ]]; then s3cmd put --config s3cmd.cfg ./build s3://develop; fi
          - if [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH = staging ]]; then s3cmd put --config s3cmd.cfg ./build s3://staging; fi
```

The two last lines will be executed only on the specified branches.

Answer (score 5):

You can define and re-use steps with [YAML Anchors](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/).

- anchor `&` to define a chunk of configuration
- alias `*` to refer to that chunk elsewhere

And the source branch is saved in a default [variable](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-in-pipelines/) called `BITBUCKET_BRANCH`

You'd also need to pass the build results (in this case the `build/` folder) from one step to the next, which is done with [artifacts](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/).

Combining all three will give you the following config:

```yaml
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build
        name: Build
        script:
          - cd source
          - npm install
          - npm build
        artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step.
          - ./build

    - step: &s3-transfer
        name: Transfer to S3
        script:
          - s3cmd put --config s3cmd.cfg ./build s3://${BITBUCKET_BRANCH}

pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build
  
  develop:
    - step: *build
    - step: *s3-transfer

  staging:
    - step: *build
    - step: *s3-transfer
```

You can now also use glob patterns as mentioned in the [referenced post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304478/bitbucket-pipelines-multiple-branches-with-same-steps) and steps for both `develop` and `staging` branches in one go:

```yaml
  "{develop,staging}":
    - step: *build
    - step: *s3-transfer
```

Comment: Spectacular...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's in the works. Hopefully available soon.

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12750/allow-multiple-steps?_ga=2.262592203.639241276.1502122373-95544429.1500927287